# Polymer RTL text based on an attribute

Tags: polymer

In my project I need to support Arabic and English, to do so I do the following:

```
<div class="{{ {'align-right': currentLanguageCode == 'ar'} | tokenList }}">{{languages[currentLanguageCode].supervisorName}}</div>
```

The above line will be repeated for every text rendering.

So I thought it will be better if I could do something like this:

**bilingual-text.html**

```
<polymer-element name="bilingual-text" attributes="languageCode">
    <template>
       <content></content>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            languageCodeChanged: function() {
                if (this.languageCode == 'ar') {
                    // add .align-right class.
                } else {
                    // remove .align-right class.
                }               
            }
        })
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

**Then**

```
<bilingual-text languageCode="ar">{{languages['ar'].supervisorName}}</bilingual-text>
```

Is there any way to implement something like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Polymeric way

However, a Polymeric way to approach this is to use `reflect: true` when publishing the  `languageCode` property. In that way, you can style this element based on this attr and/or it's value:

```
:host([languageCode="ar"]) {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

Here's a working demo:

```html
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.js"></script>

<polymer-element name="bilingual-text" attributes="languageCode">
    <template>
       <style>
         :host {
           display: block;
         }
         :host([languageCode="ar"]) {
           direction: rtl;
         }
       </style>
       <content></content>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            publish: {
              languageCode: {value: null, reflect: true}
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>


<bilingual-text>I'm LTR</bilingual-text>
<bilingual-text languageCode="ar">I'm RTL</bilingual-text>
```

#### Traditional way

Define `languageCodeChanged()` and call:

```
this.classList.toggle('align-right', this.languageCode == 'ar');
```